# Java Scanner Input String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

With a scanner, you use `input.nextInt()` for an `int` or `input.nextDouble()` for a `double`.

Why do you use `input.nextLine()` for a `String` instead of `input.nextString()`?

Comment: Because the whole line is a string? Then you would just call it a line...

Comment: I think you could be confused because it takes the whole line (including spaces) excluding any line separator at the end.

Comment: Yes, I am confused haha, just started to try and learn java. I'm only asking about the specific (Line) in the entire line of String line = input.nextLine();

Comment: My question is why wouldn't it be    String line = input.nextString();  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to `nextString()` is `next()`, which returns the next *token*, which by default is the next "word" (which is controlled by setting the delimiter, that defaults to whitespace).

`nextLine()` returns the (rest of the) current line (up to but not including the new line char(s)), **regardless of the delimiter**. That's why it's called *line* not *String*, because "line" most accurately describes what it does, rather than what type it returns which wouldn't distinguish itself from `next()`

Answer (score 1):

> Naming conventions make programs more understandable by making them
>   easier to read. They can also give information about the function of
>   the identifier-for example, whether it's a constant, package, or
>   class-which can be helpful in understanding the code.

This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line. so:

**Why would you call it nextString() if this method returns a line?**

[9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Thank you, so what it's returning is not a String?

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class takes input and tries to convert it into mentioned datatype.
If you have written `nextDouble` then it will try to convert data to Double datatype. If the conversion fails then it will throw an error.

In case of nextLine, it will take the complete next line and convert it to string because string can be n characters long.
`this is a test message` is a string value.

**String data can contain spaces whereas any other datatype won't.**

For nextLine(), Scanner will match the string with `LINE_PATTERN = ".*(\r\n|[\n\r  ])|.+$"` regex.

For nextDouble() or any other method you pass invalid input then it will throw an exception of `java.util.InputMismatchException` type.

Comment: Thank you I think I understand it now, but if line is a data type why can it be used as the value after String in the input line? Also, why dont you say String instead of Line since it would be a String?

Comment: i guess because a String can hold new lines separator too

Comment: So a line is within a string? And an int or double, etc. don't have anything else within them, so that's why you just use Int, Double, etc.?

Comment: Line could be String. But a string could be multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

To add up on other answers, all native types have **fixed** size in bytes (i.e. `byte` is 1, `char`and `short` is 2, `long` and `double` is 8, ...) so it is easy for `Scanner` to read just that amount of bytes and return the appropriate result.

Now, how many bytes is a `String`? If it were C, it would be "*until a nul character is found*", but nul characters are legal in Java strings so you can't know where to stop reading. That's why there is no `nextString()` method.

Instead, you could arbitrarily decide to end a string at a specific character, and that character ended up being the newline `\r\n` combination. The correct name for that method is then `nextLine()`.